# Is a null check required for array initialization in C? Can array initialization in C fail?

Tags: c, memory-management, low-level

I know that in C it is good practice to check for NULL pointer every time malloc() or calloc() is called. Do I have to do the same for array initialization? For example:

```
int sigcheck[5];
if (sigcheck == NULL) {return;}
```

Is line 2 necessary? If I'm not wrong, array initialization works like calling calloc() under the hood, does this under-the-hood functioning take the possibility of NULL into account or is it necessary/good practice for us to do it ourselves.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. An array owns the memory on its own. It does not need any `calloc` call or similar to get memory assigned. It can never be `NULL`.

Comment: Only problem with arrays is with *VLA* (Variable Length Arrays). `int n; if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); int vla[n];` may (silently) fail at runtime if `n` is large enough to make it fail. If this happens there is no check either :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [malloc](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/):

> If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned.

So you should check whether `malloc` returns `NULL` precisely because it might fail to allocate you the requested chunk (although this is usually unlikely).

Static allocation does not call `calloc` under the hood, since that would allocate your array on the *heap* and not on the *stack*. The space needed for static allocations is determined at compile time, and if sufficient amount of memory cannot be allocated your program will fail to load. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438900/what-happens-when-there-is-not-enough-memory-for-a-static-allocation-in-c).

Comment: Interesting. So array[8] cannot fail since the size is known at compile time. What happens if I use a dynamically allocated array like array[myVariable], cant that fail to initialize?

Comment: That's another issue. Variable-length arrays are permitted in C99 in _local_ (and not global) scope only, and in that case, it's again the compiler that determines and allocates the size.

Comment: You can't initialize variable-length arrays, you can only assign to them in run-time.

Comment: if your program fails to allocate (rather than initialize) a VLA, the program should stop unilaterally — in my experience, it crashes.  It means you've got a stack overflow (or over-allocation); you've tried to allocate too much space on the stack (which is normally limited to 8 MiB on Unix-like systems and 1 MiB on Windows).

Answer (score 7):

> it is good practice to check for NULL pointer every time malloc() or calloc() is called

Yes, because those are *functions documented to return NULL upon failure*. That's the sole reason why.

> do I have to do the same for array initialization

No.

> Is line 2 necessary?

No, it doesn't make any sense. The array can't have address null, it always holds a memory position somewhere - where it ends up depends on something that C calls *storage duration*. In this case it either has *static storage duration* or *automatic storage duration*, depending on if it was allocated outside a function or inside a function.

> If I'm not wrong, array initialization works like calling calloc() under the hood

You are wrong. `calloc` is a special case used for explicit memory allocation by the programmer, so called *allocated storage duration*. `malloc` family of functions is *never* called implicitly or silently. (Unless you call a function which claims to call `malloc` in turn, such as `strdup`.)

You might find this question interesting: [A program uses different regions of memory for static objects, automatic objects, and dynamically allocated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52855674/a-program-uses-different-regions-of-memory-for-static-objects-automatic-objects)

Comment: Overall, in case you are coming from Java or similar language where most things are silently stored on the heap... forget all about that. C is a completely different language.

Answer (score 3):

Memory for arrays is allocated like memory for any other variable type - there's no separate `calloc` or similar call under the hood.  After the line

```
int sigcheck[5];
```

what you wind up with in memory is

```
          +---+
sigcheck: |   | sigcheck[0]
          +---+ 
          |   | sigcheck[1]
          +---+ 
           ...
          +---+
          |   | sigcheck[4]
          +---+
```

So there's no need to perform a `NULL` check against `sigcheck` in this case.

Where people get confused is that under most conditions the *expression* `sigcheck` will be converted, or "decay", from type "5-element array of `int`" to type "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  This concept often gets garbled to where people think `sigcheck` is a pointer object separate from the array itself, but it isn't.

When you allocate memory dynamically through `malloc` or `calloc`, such as

```
int *sigcheck = calloc( 5, sizeof *sigcheck );
```

then (assuming the request succeeds) what you wind up with in memory is

```
          +---+
sigcheck: |   | ---+
          +---+    |
            +------+
            |  
            V
          +---+
          |   | sigcheck[0]
          +---+
          |   | sigcheck[1]
          +---+ 
           ...
          +---+
          |   | sigcheck[4]
          +---+
```

In this case the `sigcheck` *is* a separate object from the array elements.  And because `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` will return `NULL` if the memory request cannot be satisfied, then you *do* need to make a `NULL` check on `sigcheck`:

```
int *sigcheck = calloc( 5, sizeof *sigcheck );
if ( sigcheck )
{
  // do stuff
}
else
{
  // memory allocation failed, handle as appropriate
}
```